# Ag Grid: clicking button in cell causes grid to re-render

Tags: typescript, ag-grid-react

I am using a cell renderer inside my Ag-Grid to trigger a download of data via api call.

I want to show a loading symbol, but when the button is clicked, the Ag-Grid is re-rendered again.

Example column def:

```
const colDef = [
{
 header: ‘xxx’,
 field: ‘xxx’,
 cellRenderer: ‘agGroupCellRenderer’,
 cellRendererParams: {
   innerRenderer: ‘CustomCellRenderer’
}
}
]


const CustomCellRenderer = (props) => {
```

// render cell + handleDownload function
}

Any ideas how to fix this?